# How to Read Special Character from Text File in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, utf-8

I am at a complete loss.

Right now, I have a text file (named "Test.txt") that contains: `‘Test’`.

I also have a simple NodeJS script:

```
console.log(require('fs').readFileSync("Test.txt").toString());
```

---

When I run the program, I want it to output: `‘Test’`. However, the output of this program is:

```
�Test�
```

---

I am at a complete loss, because if I insert the text directly:

```
console.log("‘Test’");
```

it outputs the identical text without any issue.

---

I've tried changing the encoding for both `readFileSync` and `toString`, but I've had no success. It baffles me since `‘` and `’` are both utf-8 characters. So they should be completely compatible, right?

How can I read the text file so that the resulting string is identical to the string literal used in the second example?

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong here but ‘ is different to '. Try using the second character instead if that doesn't stop what you are trying to do?

instead of

```
‘Test’
```

use

```
'Test'
```

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion, but this is not a case in which I'm looking to use typical single-quotes. I'm specifically trying to obtain the special quotes presented in the original question. I must be able to read and save the characters as they are presented, simple substitutions are unacceptable unfortunately.

Comment: I think it could the toString() method causing the character misbehaviour.

console.log(require('fs').readFileSync('Test.txt', 'utf-8')) might work instead if that would work for you?

Comment: No, that didn't work. As I mentioned in the original post, I've already attempted a variety of different encodings, including 'utf-8', in both the readFileSync and toString functions.